# React - Can't render array of elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can't render an array of objects into my view using JSX. It does not load on the screen.

I've been learning React and I can render an array of strings, but not the array of objects.

Here is my component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

export default class PokedexGridComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(props);

    this.state = {
      pokemons: [],
      all: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getPokemons();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          className="btn btn-success btn-sm mb-5"
          type="button"
          onClick={this.getPokemons}
          value="Buscar Pokemons"
        />
        <div>
          {this.state.all.map(data => {
            return <li key={data.key}>{data.name}</li>;
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }

  getPokemons = () => {
    var pokemon = [];
    fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=20&limit=964")
      .then(data => {
        return data.json();
      })
      .then(data => {
        data["results"].forEach(data => {
          pokemon.push(data.name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + data.name.slice(1));
        });

        this.setState({ pokemons: pokemon });
        return this.state.pokemons;
      })
      .then(data => {
        var tmp = [];
        this.state.pokemons.forEach((data, idx) => {
          fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${data.toLowerCase()}`)
            .then(data => {
              return data.json();
            })
            .then(data => {
              tmp.push({
                name: data.name,
                image: data.sprites.front_default,
                key: idx
              });
            });
        });

        this.setState({ all: tmp });
        console.log(this.state.all);
      });
  };
}
```

The console returns the array of objects but can't map it on render method.

May anyone help me?

Comment: You have a async problem, you should use `Promise.all`

Answer (score 0):

The `setState` method is async so if you need to do something after updated the state you would need to use the second parameter that is a function that will be executed after updating the state.

```
this.setState({ pokemons: pokemon }, function(){
   //perform what you need with the updated
})
```

Another issue you are having is that you are updating before the requests have arrived. You can collect all your promises and apply them `Promise.all`:

```
const requests = []
pokemons.forEach((data, idx) => {
  const request = fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${data.toLowerCase()}`)
    .then((data) => {
      return data.json();
    })
  requests.push(request)
})

const tmp = [];
Promise.all(request).then((arrayOfResults) => {
  //Here you have the responses to iterate
  arrayOfResults.forEach((data) => {
    tmp.push({
      name: data.name,
      image: data.sprites.front_default,
      key: idx
    })
  })
  this.setState({all: tmp}, function(){
    //here you can see the state after update
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Works with `Promise.all`, thank you *@SergioEscudero* and *@Vencovsky*.

Here is the modified code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class PokedexGridComponent extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        pokemons: [],
        pokeComplete: []
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.getPokemons();
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <input className="btn btn-success btn-sm mb-5" type="button" onClick={this.getPokemons} value="Buscar Pokemons" />
            <div>
               {
                   (this.state.pokeComplete.map((data) => {
                       return (<li>{data.name} | {data.img}</li>)
                   }))
               }
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

getPokemons = () => {
    var pokemons = [];
    fetch("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?offset=20&limit=964")
        .then((data) => {
            return data.json();
        })
        .then((data) => {
            data["results"].forEach((data) => {
                pokemons.push(data.name)
            })

            return pokemons;
        }).then((data) => {
            var arrayReq = [];
            data.forEach((x) => {
                var req = fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/${x.toLowerCase()}`)
                    .then((data) => {
                        return data.json();
                    })
                arrayReq.push(req);
            })

            var tmp = [];
            Promise.all(arrayReq)
                .then((e) => {
                    e.forEach((x) => {
                        tmp.push({
                            name: x.name,
                            img: x.sprites.front_default
                        })
                    })
                })
                .then(() => {
                    this.setState({ pokeComplete: tmp });
                })
        })
    }
}
```